# Как организовать хранилище проектов на github?

Tags: git, github

Здравствуйте, хочу сделать хранилище проектов на гитхабе, но так как я пользуюсь им на уровне новичка у меня возникла сложность с организацией. Сейчас для этих целей использую google drive он удобен тем что имеется быстрый доступ к нужным данным с различных устройств, но я подумал что github в этом смысле еще удобнее. Сложность заключается в том что я не знаю можно ли сделать в репозитории github похожую структуру как и в google drive чтобы по надобности скачивать нужную папку с нужным проектом, а не весь репозиторий целиком? А идея с созданием отдельного репозитория для отдельного проекта кажется мне не практичной.

В любом случае жду ваших комментариев и советов по этому поводу, может кто предложит стороннее более универсальное решение.

Comment: Один репозиторий = один проект. Но нет, каждый второй спрашивает, как ему микроскопом гвозди забивать сподручнее, а потом жалуются, почему они вроде используют лучшие практики, но зарплата ниже, чем у вон того парня.

Comment: *"А идея с созданием отдельного репозитория для отдельного проекта кажется мне не практичной."* исключительно из-за отсутствия опыта работы с Git. Потому что практически все делают именно так. Можете развернуть мысль, почему вы считаете такой подход непрактичным?

Comment: @D-side Могу, вечером допишу в ответ.

Comment: @AK я вообще-то не вам, но ладно :D

Answer (score 1):

Не надо забивать микроскоп гвоздями:

> Один репозиторий = один проект.

Иначе зачем вам гит? Продолжайте и дальше пользоваться файлохранилищами.